# How is this expression evaluated

Tags: ruby

Can anyone say how ruby evaluates this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a, b = b, a + b
```

a will be 2 and b will be 3, not 4 as you might expect

It seems that instead of working from left to right it does both sides in parallel somehow?

Comment: Why might you expect 4? In most languages I know the righthand side of an assignment operation is always evaluated first. Should you happen to know PHP, the equivalent there would be `list($a, $b) = [$b, $a + $b]`; the lefthand side is merely "unpacking" the righthand side arguments.

Comment: @Stefan It looks like so, but it is not.. :-)

Comment: @Marty Wallace I guess Ruby uses some temp variables while doing parallel assignments, same like Java uses temp variables to perform post increment/decrements.

Comment: Don't write false/wrong expectations. I do not expect `4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expressed as :-

```
a = 1
b = 2
a, b = b, (a + b)
a # => 2
b # => 3
```

This is called parallel assignment. Here all *RHS* expressions will be evaluated first (left to right). After that assignment will be happened from *left to right*.

It means, the calculation as follows :

```
a, b = b, a + b
a, b = 2, (2 + 1)
a, b = 2, 3 # now the real assignment will be happened here.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called parallel association, and, like name suggests, it works like all the assignments are done in parallel. You can for example write:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a, b = b, a

a   #=> 2
b   #=> 1
```

Comment: Multiple assignment in the context of Ruby refers to something like `a = b = 1`.

Comment: @sawa While I agree with you, the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment) actually calls `a, b = 1, 2` a "multiple assignment".

Comment: @toro2k You are right. There seems to be inconsistency even among the developers.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 1
b = 2
a, b = b, a + b
a
#=> 2
b 
#=> 3
```

Here first rvalue is assigned to first lvalue and the result of second rexp is assigned to second lvalue. These assignments are `parallel` in nature not `sequential`.

`a, b = b, a` is a swap operation using `parallel` assignments. This makes me think Ruby might be using `temporary` variables to perform `parallel` assignments. I invite for corrections here.